# How to start a delay job correctly using Upstart?

Tags: 12.04, upstart, openvpn

The current script:

```
start on (net-device-up
          and local-filesystems
          and runlevel [2345]
          and started rsyslog)
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn

exec /usr/sbin/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/devops/config
```

The problem is if it failed to start for some reasons:

```
Sep 24 01:55:07 p vpn-devops[5075]: Cannot load certificate file /etc/openvpn/devops/server.crt: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory
: error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib: error:140AD002:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file:system lib
Sep 24 01:55:07 p vpn-devops[5075]: Exiting
```

Upstart still think that it is started and exit with 0 status immediately.

My first try:

```
post-start script
  for try in $(seq 9); do
    if [ nc -q0 -zu localhost 1194 ]; then
      exit 0
    fi
    sleep 1
  done
  exit 1
end script
```

I thought that it will work but actually it's not. The reason is [exit code is ignored](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/wiki/Stanzas#post-start) in the `post-start`.

My second try:

```
expect fork
respawn

pre-start script
  /usr/sbin/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/devops/config
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    exit 1
  fi
end script

script
  while kill -0 $(cat /var/run/openvpn/devops.pid); do
    sleep 1
  done
end script
```

Now the exit status is correct in case of failure:

```
start openvpn-devops
start: Job failed to start

echo $?
1
```

but `start` hangs (does not return the shell prompt) in normal case although the pid is tracking correctly:

```
status openvpn-devops
openvpn-devops start/pre-start, process 7565

cat /var/run/openvpn/devops.pid
7565
```

The same thing happened if I use:

```
expect daemon
/usr/sbin/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/devops/config --daemon
```

My third try:

```
expect fork
exec /usr/sbin/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/devops/config --daemon
```

then `start` worked but it track the wrong pid because the number of forks is not correct:

```
start openvpn-devops
openvpn-devops start/running, process 7720

status openvpn-devops
openvpn-devops start/running, process 7720

cat /var/run/openvpn/devops.pid
7715

ps -ef | grep vpn
nobody    7715     1  0 02:41 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/devops/config --daemon
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current script is correct, it does what it should do.

Second script hangs forever because `/usr/sbin/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/devops/config` never exits, it runs in foreground.

Third script also hangs but because `openvpn --daemon` only forks once.

`expect daemon
/usr/sbin/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/devops/config --daemon`

Changed it to `expect fork` will work if config file is correct. If config file is wrong, openvpn won't fork, so it won't work correctly.

TL;DR: just stick with current script.